How to connect two surfaces to create a solid on MATLAB?
So I have this code where I am creating two surfaces using zernike coefficients and polynomials. Now I want to connect them and make it as a solid object. How can I do that in Matlab? The zernike_coefficients.mat file gives coeffs_CF and coeffs_CB as a 45x1 array and the order_CF=8 and order_CB=8

clear; clc;

%% Zernike elevation data. OS - left eye; OD - right eye;
Rf_OS = 3e-2; % front surface radius
Rb_OS = 3e-2; % back surface radius

% Zernike coefficients
load("zernike_coefficients.mat");

% coefficients and order match
cnt_CF_new = (order_CF+1)*(order_CF+2)/2;
cnt_CB_new = (order_CB+1)*(order_CB+2)/2;

% define the circle with front radius
gridSize = 100;
polarDataFront = [Rf_OS; gridSize];
polarDataBack = [Rb_OS; gridSize];

[x_f, y_f, z_f] = reconstructSurface(coeffs_CF, order_CF, polarDataFront);

[x_b, y_b, z_b] = reconstructSurface(coeffs_CB, order_CB, polarDataBack);

% Plot the reconstructed surface
figure; set(gcf,'WindowState','Maximized');
surf(x_f, y_f, -z_f);
hold on;
surf(x_b,y_b,-z_b);
title('Reconstructed Surface using Zernike Polynomials');
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z (Elevation)');
grid on;

function [x_fit, y_fit, z_fit] = reconstructSurface(coeffs, order, polarData)
    % Generate a grid of polar coordinates
    radius = polarData(1)/2; % radius
    gridSize = polarData(2); % grid size
    theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, gridSize); % polar coordinate theta
    rho = linspace(0, 1, gridSize); % polar coordinate rho normalized
    [THETA, RHO] = meshgrid(theta, rho);

    % Initialize Zernike polynomial matrix
    num_polynomials = (order + 1) * (order + 2) / 2;
    Zpoly = zeros(numel(RHO), num_polynomials);
    
    % Calculate Zernike polynomials for each order up to specified order
    k = 1;
    for n = 0:order
        for m = -n:2:n
            if mod(n - abs(m), 2) == 0  % Ensure n - m is even
                Zpoly(:, k) = zernike(n, m, RHO(:), THETA(:));
                k = k + 1;
            end
        end
    end
    
    % Reconstruct the surface
    z_fit = Zpoly * coeffs';
    z_fit = reshape(z_fit, gridSize, gridSize);
    
    % Convert polar coordinates back to Cartesian coordinates
    [x_fit, y_fit] = pol2cart(THETA, RHO);
    x_fit = x_fit.*radius;
    y_fit = y_fit.*radius;
end

function Z = zernike(n, m, rho, theta)
    R = zeros(size(rho));
    for k = 0:((n - abs(m)) / 2)
        R = R + ((-1)^k * factorial(n - k) / ...
            (factorial(k) * factorial((n + abs(m)) / 2 - k) * factorial((n - abs(m)) / 2 - k))) ...
            * rho.^(n - 2*k);
    end
    
    % Normalize the Zernike polynomial
    norm_factor = sqrt((2 * (n + 1)) / (1 + (m == 0)));
    
    % Calculate the Zernike polynomial Z_n^m(rho, theta)
    if m >= 0
        Z = norm_factor * R .* cos(m * theta);
    else
        Z = norm_factor * R .* sin(abs(m) * theta);
    end
end


What does "make it as a solid object" actually mean? In other words, what kind of data structure do you want to use to represent the solid?

Similar to Wolfgang asked, why do you need "a solid object" or what is going to be its use case?

@WolfgangBangerth @nicoguaro♦ I want to make it as one object, which I will convert into an stl file for finite element analysis

But how do you intend to represent the object? I assume that because you need an STL file, that you want to represent it as a triangulated surface that is closed?

Yes exactly. Just like a triangular surface that is closed.
